# How can I use ptr to ptr in idapython?

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

in hey-rays api there's a method:

```py
def find_def(self, *args) -> "minsn_t *":
    r"""
    find_def(self, op, p_i1, i2, fdflags) -> minsn_t
    @param op: mop_t const &
    @param p_i1: minsn_t **
    @param i2: minsn_t const *
    @param fdflags: int
    """
    return _ida_hexrays.mblock_t_find_def(self, *args)
```

which will need a ptr to ptr to a instruction.

but I didn't find any method can create a minsn_t **. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not a real answer, but if you can usually pass null (`None`) to those. If you're trying to get the parent minstruction, though, because your result resides in an moperand, you might be able to combine `build_def_list` to get an `mlist_t`, and then `mblock_t.for_all_uses` if you only need it for a single mblock. In my (limited) experience, `mlist_t` and the `for_all_*` methods are more reliable for doing searches, especially because you're not limited to just an mblock.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it myself too.